# Media Print CSS with a CR80 size

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, printing

I've been working on an ID page for my job's resource page, which is meant to allow my boss to print IDs directly from a browser instead of using the printer's software. I've completed all the functional aspects of the ID, except the proper layout size when printing.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="printarea">
    <table>
        <!-- Other components that include the table so I wouldn't use a grid system. -->
    </table>
</div>
```

And the CSS for the Media Print looks as follows:

```
@media print {
    #header {
        display: none;
    }

    #printarea, #printarea * {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

The table size is exactly the size of a CR80 ID. I've tried using the media print with specific sizes for CR80 IDs, but it didn't work, or I was doing it wrong. The normal HTML view looks fine, but when I preview the print, it always shows everything in the top left corner and never fills the whole area. I've been struggling with this for a month already. Can anyone help me with this issue?